# Crystal Report Auto Round Decimal

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

While fetching data from SQL Server into Crystal report it's auto rounding my value and shows useless zero into report.

[image: Crystal Report Screen Short]

[image: Database Value Screen Short]

i wanna show same as it is like database without rounding

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it for you.

Right click on the field > Format > Number Tab > Customize > Under decimal select 1.0